# Convergence of $\sum \frac{\ln n}{n^2 -3n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does $\sum_{n=4} \frac{\ln n}{n^2 -3n}$ converge? My "gut feeling" tells me that it converges since $n^2$ grows faster than $\ln(n)$. But I cannot come up with an argument. I feel that comparison test is the way to go. I tried

$$\sum \frac{\ln n}{n^2 - 3n}<\sum\frac{n}{n^2 - 3n}=\sum\frac{1}{n-3},$$

which doesn't work. I also tried

$$\sum\frac{\ln n}{n^2 - 3n}<\sum\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2 -3n}<\sum\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}-3\sqrt{n}},$$
 since I want a p-series that converges. I want to get rid of the $3\sqrt{n}$, but not sure how. Specifically, we do not have

$$\sum\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}-3\sqrt{n}}<\sum\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually,
your second one
does show convergence.
The $3\sqrt{n}$
can be ignored,
and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^p}
$
converges for
$p > 1$.

To show why
the $3\sqrt{n}$
can be ignored,
note that

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{n^{3/2}-3\sqrt{n}}
&=2\dfrac1{2n^{3/2}-2\sqrt{n}}\\
&=2\dfrac1{n^{3/2}+n^{3/2}-2\sqrt{n}}\\
&\le 2\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}\\
\end{array}
$

when
$n^{3/2} > 2\sqrt{n}$
or
$n > 2$.

Comment: Edited my post. Basically I want to get rid of that $3\sqrt{n}$ but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I added a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Use a comparison test with, say, $\sum_n n^{-3/2}$.

$$ \dfrac{\ln(n)/(n^2-3n)}{n^{-3/2}} = \dfrac{\ln n}{n^{1/2} (1 - 3/n)} \to 0\ \text{as}\ n \to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

For every $\delta>0
 $ we have that exists some $n_{0}
 $ such that $\log\left(n\right)<n^{\delta},\,\forall n\geq n_{0}
 $. So $$\sum_{n\geq n_{0}}\frac{\log\left(n\right)}{n^{2}-3n}<\sum_{n\geq n_{0}}\frac{1}{n^{2-\delta}-3n^{1-\delta}}\sim\sum_{n\geq n_{0}}\frac{1}{n^{2-\delta}}$$ so it is sufficient to take $\delta<1$ and we have done.

Answer (score 2):

The general term is *equivalent* to
$$\frac{\ln n}{n^2-3n}\sim_\infty\frac{\ln n}{n^2}=\frac1{n^2\ln^{-1}n},$$
which is a convergent *Bertrand's series*.

*Reminder:* A Bertrand's  series: $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge2}\frac1{n^{\alpha}\ln^{\beta}n}$, is convergent if $\;\alpha>1\;$ or $\;\alpha=1, \,\beta>1$, divergent otherwise.

Comment: +1. Too few people use asymptotic comparison tests, although these tests answer 90% of the questions about series convergence on MSE

Comment: And often much more easily, with some practice, than more ‘standard’ methods. Some people love to reinvent the wheel…

Answer (score 1):

You could show the convergence using standard tests.

Let us try the ratio test $$u_n=\frac{\log (n)}{n^2 -3n}$$ $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\times\frac{n^2 -3n}{n^2-n-2}=\frac{\log(n)+\log(1+\frac 1n)}{\log(n)}\times\frac{n^2 -3n}{n^2-n-2}$$ So $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\to 1$ when $n\to \infty$ and the ratio test is inconclusive.

So, let us try [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test) $$n\left(\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}-1\right)=n\left(\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)}\times\frac{n^2-n-2}{n^2 -3n}-1\right)$$ and use Taylor expansion for large $n$ (using the same trick as above for $\log(n+1)$). You should end with $$n\left(\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}-1\right)=\left(2-\frac{1}{\log \left({n}\right)}\right)+\frac{6-\frac{5}{2 \log
   \left({n}\right)}}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which tends to $2$ when $n\to \infty$. So, absolute convergence.

Answer (score 0):

There is the upper bound:
$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2-3n} = \dfrac14\left(\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac{\ln n}{n-3}-\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac{\ln n}{n}\right) = \dfrac14\left(\ln4+\dfrac12\ln5+\dfrac13\ln6+\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac{\ln(n+3)}{n}-\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac{\ln n}{n}\right) = \dfrac14\left(\ln4+\dfrac12\ln5+\dfrac13\ln6+\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac1n\ln\dfrac{n+3}{n}\right) = \dfrac14\left(\ln4+\dfrac12\ln5+\dfrac13\ln6+\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac1n\ln\left(1+\dfrac3n\right)\right)\\<
\dfrac14\left(\ln4+\dfrac12\ln5+\dfrac13\ln6+3\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac1{n^2}\right).$$
Using well-known [formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2Fn%5E2)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}6,$$
easy to get

$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2-3n}<\dfrac14\left(\dfrac16\ln4^65^36^2+3\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}6-1-\dfrac14-\dfrac19\right)\right)\approx0.91.$$
So the sum converges, as increasing and bounded above function.

Comment: This is way too messy and advanced an answer for such a basic question. There exists a very good chance the OP doesn't even know $\;\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Wolfram Alpha exists.

Comment: Of course, and under the same logic then nobody should ask anything.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for help. Refusal of good advice is incompatible with wisdom.